# Flash banner placed over bottom toolbar and popup windows

Tags: flash

My flash banner is placed above my light box popup windows and my Wibiya Toolbar.

See attached file.

Here is my flash banner code:

Answer (score 0):

I've seen a fix for this by setting a param as follows:

`<PARAM NAME="WMODE" VALUE="transparent">`

and `WMODE="transparent"` in the `EMBED` tag.

Then the Flash should behave properly if you set a `z-index` in your CSS.

[Here's some example code](http://www.flashdesignerzone.com/tutorials/t1026.php).